# Return name of last data frame column which is not NA in each row

Tags: r, dataframe, na

I have a dataset consisting of multiple cases that are stamped either 1 OR NA. I'm trying to figure out a way to return the name of the last column (highest numbered stamp) that is not NA for each row.

Here are some sample data:

```
PIN <- c("case1", "case2", "case3", "case4", "case5")
STAMP_1 <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
STAMP_2 <- c(NA, 1, 1, NA, 1)
STAMP_3 <- c(1, NA, 1, 1, NA)
STAMP_4 <- c(NA, NA, 1, 1, NA)
STAMP_5 <- c(1, NA, NA, 1, NA)
data <- data.frame(PIN, STAMP_1, STAMP_2, STAMP_3, STAMP_4, STAMP_5)
```

I'd like to figure out a way to return a data frame that will have  columns: "case1", "case2", "case3", "case4", "case5" AND "STAMP_5", "STAMP_2", "STAMP_4", "STAMP_5", "STAMP_2" in this case.

Comment: To clarify, so for case 1, it would be stamp 5? and case 2, it will be stamp 2, and so on?

Comment: FYI, your code threw and error in the `as.data.frame` call. I think you meant to use `data.frame()` or `cbind.data.frame()` here (I edited your Q to the former), but do check this is what you intended.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I meant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a method with `max.col`, `is.na` and `names`. `max.col` finds the column with the maximum value for each row. Here, we feed it the value of `is.na`, which is TRUE or FALSE and use ties.method="last" to take the final non-NA value. This position is used to index `names(dat)`.

```
data.frame(PIN=dat$PIN,
           stamp=names(dat)[-1][max.col(!is.na(dat[-1]), ties.method="last")])
    PIN   stamp
1 case1 STAMP_5
2 case2 STAMP_2
3 case3 STAMP_4
4 case4 STAMP_5
5 case5 STAMP_2
```

In the case that you have an entire row with NAs, `max.col` will return the final position of the row (a silent failure?). One way to return an NA rather than that position is to use a trick with NA and exponentiation. Here, we `apply` through the rows and find any NA rows with `any` rows that have at least one non-NA value return FALSE (or 0).

```
data.frame(PIN=dat$PIN,
           stamp=names(dat)[-1][
                max.col(!is.na(dat[-1]), ties.method="last") * NA^!rowSums(!is.na(dat[-1]))])
```

I switched from `applyapply(dat[-1], 1, function(x) all(is.na(x)))` to `!rowSums(!is.na(dat[-1]))` after Frank's suggestion. This should be quite a bit faster than `apply`.

Comment: And if a row is entirely NA, will this return NA or...?

Comment: Oh yeah, I suppose that's worth adding.

Comment: Instead of `apply`, I guess there's also `rowSums(!is.na(dat[-1])) == 0` or something.

Comment: Thanks, @Frank. I'll take a look at the link you posted when I get minute. The `rowSums` method is definitely better.

Comment: Thank you! Other responses look good as well, but this did the trick! Didn't need the NA exponentiation trick as there are no rows will all NAs. Max.col seems like a really useful function.

Answer (score 3):

By using `dplyr` with `melt` (from `reshape`)

```
dat=melt(dat)
dat=na.omit(dat)
dat%>%group_by(PIN)%>%slice(n())

# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   PIN [5]
     PIN variable value
  <fctr>   <fctr> <dbl>
1  case1  STAMP_5     1
2  case2  STAMP_2     1
3  case3  STAMP_4     1
4  case4  STAMP_5     1
5  case5  STAMP_2     1
```

Comment: @Jon Thank you ~ Jon

Answer (score 2):

Base R

```
temp = cbind(NA, data[-1])
temp = temp * col(temp)
data.frame(PIN = data$PIN,
           STAMP = names(temp)[max.col(m = replace(temp, is.na(temp), 0),
                                       ties.method = "first")])
#    PIN   STAMP
#1 case1 STAMP_5
#2 case2 STAMP_2
#3 case3 STAMP_4
#4 case4 STAMP_5
#5 case5 STAMP_2
```