# Find last of several columns that is not NA (tidyverse)

Tags: r, tidyverse

Not sure what I'm doing wrong but I'm struggling getting the index per row of the last column (among several columns) that is not NA.

Using tidyverse and across, I'm getting as many output columns as input columns where I'd expect one single output column with the index of the respective column.

```
dat <- data.frame(id = c(1, 2, 3),
                  x  = c(1, NA, NA),
                  y  = c(NA, NA, NA),
                  z  = c(3, 1, NA))
```

I tried the following (among others, inspired by this one: [Return last data frame column which is not NA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45947603/return-last-data-frame-column-which-is-not-na)):

```
dat %>%
  mutate(last = across(-id, ~max.col(!is.na(.x), ties.method="last")))
```

Expected outcome would be:

```
  id  x  y  z  last
1  1  1 NA  3  3
2  2 NA NA  1  3
3  3 NA NA NA  NA
```

Comment: `max.col` expects a `matrix` (ref: [`?max.col`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/maxCol.html)), whereas `.x` is a vector, so the first effective call is `max.col(c(1,1,NA))` (which returns a length-3 vector, `c(1,1,NA)`.

Comment: I see., but changing .x to . will lead to getting several new columns.

Comment: probably you should consider `dat %>% cbind(last=max.col(!is.na(.[-1]), ties.method = "last"))` instead

Comment: Second, your third row `NA` is inconsistent with `max*`: even though `!is.na(.x)` is false for all three, the max of three falses (similar to `max(c(0,0,0))`) is still valid, therefore it will still return 3. It sounds like you want special logic for that, likely a custom function.

Comment: You almost certainly do not want to use `.` instead of `.x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tidyverse` isn't really suitable for row-wise operation. Most of the times reshaping the data into long format (as shown in @Rui Barradas answer) is a good approach.

Here is one way using `rowwise` keeping the data wide.

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(last = {ind = which(!is.na(c_across(x:z))); 
                if(length(ind)) tail(ind, 1) else NA})

#    id     x   y        z  last
#  <dbl> <dbl> <lgl> <dbl> <int>
#1     1     1 NA        3     3
#2     2    NA NA        1     3
#3     3    NA NA       NA    NA
```

Comment: Yes, rowwise isn't nice in the tidyverse, but your solution works (and is fast). I also found a solution through reshaping, but given the size of my data set, it's pretty slow.

Answer (score 3):

The problems with your current flow:

1. `across` is going to pass one *column* at a time to the function/expression; your code needs a row or a matrix/frame. For this, `across` is not appropriate.
2. Your desired output of `NA` for the last row is inconsistent with the logic: `!is.na(.x)` should return `c(F,F,F)`, *which still has a max*. Your logic then requires a custom function, since you need to handle it differently.

Try this adaptation of `max.col` into a custom function:

```r
max.col.notna <- function (m, ties.method = c("random", "first", "last")) {
    ties.method <- match.arg(ties.method)
    tieM <- which(ties.method == eval(formals()[["ties.method"]]))
    out <- .Internal(max.col(as.matrix(m), tieM))
    m[] <- !m %in% c(0,NA) # 'm[] <-' is required to maintain the matrix shape
    replace(out, rowSums(m) == 0, NA_integer_)
}

dat %>%
  mutate(last = max.col.notna(!is.na(select(., -id)), ties.method = "last"))
#   id  x  y  z last
# 1  1  1 NA  3    3
# 2  2 NA NA  1    3
# 3  3 NA NA NA   NA
```

---

Note: I've edited/changed the function several times, trying to ensure a consistent API to the *intent* of this custom function. As it stands now, the `notna` in the function name to me reflects a sense of "emptiness" (either `0` or `NA`). With this logic, the function is usable with `logical` (as here) and `numeric` data. Perhaps it's overkill, but I prefer APIs that operate consistently/predictably across input classes.

Comment: Interesting solution and thanks for the explanations. I now understand wy across didn't work. I accepted the solution of @Ronak Shah, due to its shortness and simplicity, though.

Comment: That's fine, and sometimes `rowwise` is the simplest/best way to go. Realize that with larger data, `rowwise` performs *horribly*. As long as your data is under hundreds-of-rows, that should be fine (much more than that and you may feel the difference).

Comment: Yes, totally agree. That's why I usually try to avoid rowwise and c_across and use a hbyrid of `apply(across(select vars), 1, my function)`, but this didn't work here. Luckily, even with my current 55k rows, the solution did only take 2-3 seconds or so.

Answer (score 1):

An R base solution:

```
dat$last = apply(dat[,2:4], 1, 
                 FUN = function(x) ifelse(max(which(is.na(x))) == length(x), NA, max(which(is.na(x)))+1 ))

dat

# id  x  y  z last
# 1  1  1 NA  3    3
# 2  2 NA NA  1    3
# 3  3 NA NA NA   NA
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `c_across()` and `rowwise()` to do this. `rowwise()` works similar to `group_by_all()`, except it is more explicit. `c_across()` creates flat vectors out of columns (whereas `across()` creates tibbles).

If we first define a function seperately to pull out the last non-`NA` value, or return `NA` if there are none:

```
get_last <- function(x){
  y <- c(NA,which(!is.na(x)))
  y[length(y)]
}
```

We can then apply that function `c_across()` the variables we need, but only after converting into a `rowwise_df` using `rowwise()`

```
dat %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(last = get_last(c_across(x:z)))
```

Answer (score 1):

`base` R

```r
df <- data.frame(id = c(1, 2, 3),
                        x  = c(1, NA, NA),
                        y  = c(NA, NA, NA),
                        z  = c(3, 1, NA))


df$last <- apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) max(as.vector(!is.na(x)) * seq_len(length(x))))
df$last[df$last == 0] <- NA
df
#>   id  x  y  z last
#> 1  1  1 NA  3    3
#> 2  2 NA NA  1    3
#> 3  3 NA NA NA   NA
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Starting with a vector of NAs, you could step through each col and if the given element passes your `check_fun` returning `TRUE`, assign the index of that col to that element. The difference from the other answers here is that this does not check the condition row-wise or create a matrix from the data. Not sure whether creating two new temp vectors for each column is better/worse than just converting the entire data to a matrix first though.

```
library(tidyverse) # purrr and dplyr

last_matching_ind <- function(dat, check_fun){
  check_fun <- as_mapper(check_fun)
  reduce2(dat, seq_along(dat), .init = NA_integer_,
          function(prev, dat, ind) if_else(check_fun(dat), ind, prev) )
}

dat %>% 
  mutate(last = last_matching_ind(dat[-1], ~ !is.na(.x)))

#   id  x  y  z last
# 1  1  1 NA  3    3
# 2  2 NA NA  1    3
# 3  3 NA NA NA   NA
```